# Arbitrary signed and absolutely continuous measure has a derivative w.r.t a positive measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

[image]

This is an exercise from Folland Real Analysis p.92 that I am just totally stuck at...

It was not hard to prove b. and c. under the assumption of a. But then, I cannot do anything (literally anything) about $\nu$ on the set $E^c$ for the case in which $\mu(E^c) >0$. $\nu$ is not $\sigma$ finite on $E^c$, and therefore any unexpected pathological behavior can occur there.... For example, I can imagine the situation where $\nu(E^c)=\infty$ but all proper measurable subsets of $E^c$ are $\nu$-null.... How should I break through these stymies and define an appropriate $f$ on $E^c$? Could anyone please help me? I am dearly waiting for any hints......